# Symlinked Dotfiles Are Not Working

Tags: macos, filesystem, symlink

I'm on macOS Catalina and I'm trying to move all my "dotfiles" into a folder, where I can place them under version control, then symlink them back  into the home folder.  I've created a hidden ".dotfiles" folder within the home folder, moved the dotfiles into it, then symlinked them back into the home folder with:

```sh
ln -s <dotfile name> ..
```

However, terminal complains that the commands associated with those dotfiles are no longer found.  I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -l` in upper directory to see what the link points to.

You might find it should be

```sh
cd ..
ln -s dotfile_dir/dotfile_name .
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `ln` syntax is wrong, which is leading to self-referential symbolic links. For example:

```
% mkdir .dotfiles
% cd .dotfiles/
% touch .foo
% ln -s .foo ..
% cd ..
% ls -l .foo
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tph  wheel  4 Dec  5 10:38 .foo@ -> .foo
```

At this point `.foo` exists but it's a symlink to itself, not to the copy in `.dotfiles`.

Probably the easiest way to do it is to `cd ~` and make the symlinks from there:

```
% cd ~
% ln -s .dotfiles/.foo .
% ls -l .foo 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tph  wheel  14 Dec  5 10:46 .foo@ -> .dotfiles/.foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `.dotfiles` *directory* was added to `$HOME`, and you've moved the target *dot files* into it, then use the following *compound command* in **Terminal**:

<sub>**Hint:** Copy and paste the `for in do` *command*, no need to type it.</sub>

```
cd .dotfiles
for f in .??*; do [ ! "$f" == ".DS_Store" ] || continue; ln -s "${HOME}/.dotfiles/${f}" "${HOME}/${f}"; done
```

Then close and reopen **Terminal**.

This will create a proper working *symlink* for each *dot file* in the `$HOME/.dotfiles` *directory* into the `$HOME` *directory*, because *fully qualified pathnames* were used.

---

<sub>**Note:** The use of `??` in `.??*` is so you do not try making a *symlink* to `.` and `..` in the `.dotfiles` *directory* as they already exist in `$HOME` and you wouldn't want them *symlinked* anyway. Without the qualifier you'll get `ln: ..//.: File exists` and `ln: ..//..: File exists`. There could also be a `.DS_Store` file, which you do not want to *symlink* either, so `[ ! "$f" == ".DS_Store" ] || continue;` handles it.</sub>